# Getting either SMTP or SSL error after getting app password from google

Tags: python, ssl, automation, smtplib

I have started learning Python automation and following the video available on freecodecamp. in the first project while sending the email I'm either getting SMTP wrong userid or password error or this SSL error "SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)".

I changed the code a little bit, and tried different port numbers yet, not getting any results. I have already done my 2FA and been putting the random password provided by Google. I put the same emailid in 'TO' and 'From' function. I'm a complete beginner so I might be missing something or doing something wrong, kindly check the code and provide some solutions:

'''

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()


msg['Subject'] = 'Top News Stories HN [Automated Email]' + ' ' 
+str(now.day) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year)
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = TO

#attaching the email body
msg.attach(MIMEText(content, 'html'))
#fp.close()

print('Initializing Server...')

#AUTHENTICATION
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SERVER, PORT)
#server = smtplib.SMTP SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.set_debuglevel(1)   #used to see debug error messages     
server.ehlo()
#server.starttls()
#server.elho
server.login(FROM, PASS)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, msg.as_string())

print('Email Sent...')


server.quit()
```

'''

Comment: Narrow it down to one or the other. You won't get both these errors randomly. You are changing something. Get it to the point where it is always the SMTP error and then edit that code into your question. NB there is no [tag:syntax-error] here.